# Private ip dhcp for pxe boot

Tags: linux, networking

Sorry this might be a stupid question as I don't know the exact term to google. But this question has been in my mind for a while.

Let's assume machine A is the isc-dhcpd server with two interface. One private interface (eth0: 192.168.1.1) and one public interface(eth1: x.x.x.x). THe private interface have no access to internet, while the public interface can access the internet.

Now. I have a machine B without OS in the same network as Machine A. I want to use machine A to kickstart machine B. Machine A dhcpd is on interface eth0.

My question is, machine A will assigna  private IP to machine B let's say 192.168.1.2. Machine B will use machine A as gateway, but machine A's 192.168.1.1 cannot access the internet to access OS files. HOw to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you need to make your server (Machine A) into a *router*. In this way, traffic from the private network can be *routed* to the public interface and visa versa.

There are many guides on how to do this depending on what OS/distro you are using but there is already a question answered on the SU sister site, Ask Ubuntu. [How to set up a linux server as a router](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376717/how-to-set-up-a-linux-server-as-a-router).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to configure computer A as a router using `iptables` or `nftables`.  It is not enough to configure computer B with computer A as it's gateway.  Computer A must know to forward those packets to its other interface.

Additionally, PXE is not a routable protocol.  You must also configure computer A to be a PXE server, or at least configure computer A's DHCP server with a PXE helper address.